# win_unzip does not extract file

Tags: ansible

I want to install (an older version of) Eclipse on some Windows 7 hosts with Ansible.
My playbook installs Java and downloads the needed zip file, but `win_unzip` does not extract the file.

```
- name: Ensure Eclipse Luna RCP is extracted
  win_unzip:
    src: '%TEMP%\eclipse-rcp-luna-SR2-win32.zip'
    dest: '%userprofile%\Programs\eclipse_luna'
  tags: eclipse
```

When the task is executed, I can see that a `powershell` process is running on the Windows host and is consuming some CPU.
After some time I get the following result by Ansible:

```
TASK [Ensure Eclipse Luna RCP is extracted] ************
ok: [192.168.1.87] => {"changed": false,
                       "dest": "C:\\Users\\testuser\\Programs\\eclipse_luna",
                       "removed": false,
                       "src": "C:\\Users\\testuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\eclipse-rcp-luna-SR2-win32.zip"
                      }
```

The result is a bit strange because the [`win_zip` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_unzip_module.html#notes) states:

> This module is not really idempotent, it will extract the archive every time, and report a change.

Due to this I expect a `changed` and not an `ok`.
Nevertheless the folder `C:\Users\testuser\Programs\eclipse_luna` was created but is empty.

Answer (score 3):

After posting this question, I tried to extract the zip file myself and realized that the file was faulty.

After deleting the file and rerunning the playbook, `win_unzip` worked as expected.